# Formatting issue when attempting to insert new rows in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to use an alertViewController to get text, add it to my array of strings, and then reload the tableView with the newly added cell. There seems to be an issue with the formatting after it is reloaded.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    // store the tasks in an array of strings
    var tasks = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Task List"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addRow))
    }

    func addRow() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Add a task to the list", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        // add a text field
        ac.addTextField {
            (textField) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = ""
        }

        // add "cancel" and "ok" actions
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
        let createNewRow = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action -> Void in
            let text = ac.textFields?.first?.text
            self.tasks.append(text!)
            self.loadView()
        }
        ac.addAction(createNewRow)

        present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Task", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = tasks[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was you call self.loadView() instead of self.tableView.reloadData() in the alert view controller's action:

```
    let createNewRow = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action -> Void in
        let text = ac.textFields?.first?.text
        self.tasks.append(text!)
        self.tableView.reloadData() // self.loadView() is wrong.
    }
    ac.addAction(createNewRow)
```

From Apple's document: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview

> You should never call this method directly. The view controller calls
>   this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil.
>   This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view
>   property.